# How to setup e2e protractor backend request mocking/stubbing

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing, ngmocke2e

I try to setup my independent *protractor* project to **mock some of my backend requests**. Therefore, I included `angular-mocks.js` and attached another *module* within the `onPrepare()` function of my *protractor.conf.js*:

```
browser.addMockModule('httpBackend', function() {
    angular.module('httpBackend', ['myApp', 'ngMockE2E']).run(function($httpBackend) {
        $httpBackend.whenPOST(/^requests\/*/).respond(function(method, url, data) {
            var obj = {"msg": "Response!"};
            return [200, JSON.stringify(obj), {}];
        });
    })
})
```

This lets me intercept any *request* but I am not getting what I want to return in `respond()`. It seems I am just getting a `200 OK`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to let you know how I solved it:

The docs say the following:

> The respond method takes a set of static data to be returned or a function that can return an array containing response status (number), response data (string), response headers (Object), and the text for the status (string).

In my case, the *headers Object* somehow does not seem to be optional and I ended with setting it on my own before returning the *array*:

```
browser.addMockModule('httpBackend', function() {
    angular.module('httpBackend', ['myApp', 'ngMockE2E']).run(function($httpBackend) {
        $httpBackend.whenPOST(/^requests\/*/).respond(function(method, url, data) {
            var obj = {"msg": "Response!"},
                resHeader = {
                    "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0",
                    "Date": "Tue, 24 Nov 2015 17:08:57 GMT",
                    "Pragma": "no-cache",
                    "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                    "Expires": "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "origin,x-requested-with,access-control-request-headers,content-type,access-control-request-method,accept",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE",
                    "Access-Control-Credentials": "true",
                    "Content-Language": "de-DE",
                    "Access-Control-Max-Age": "3600"
                };
            return [200, JSON.stringify(obj), resHeader];
        });
    })
})
```

Anybody has a clue why this is necessary or which of its attributes is obsolete?